# Cognos pie chart with categories, can they be sectioned by series?

Tags: cognos-10

One of the managers here handed me a Cognos report she created and it has a pie chart that looks like this:
[image]

She doesn't like that the pie charts are so small and wanted to know if we can so a "section break" so that each pie chart could be on its own.  Being very new to Cognos, I have no idea if this is possible.  Can such a thing be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the section / unsection button and that works for now.